# How to remove URI encoding from file names?

Tags: command-line, rename

I realise this might be quite a simple question, but I'm still quite new to the command line and only have a grasp of basic commands.

I've downloaded some lecture presentations (~25 or so) from my University however on doing so they've been named things like...

```
L2%20Development%20of%20immune%20system.pptx
L4%20Molecular%20Recognition.pdf
```

As you can see they've downloaded with the URL encoding `%20` instead of a space.

My question is how to batch rename all of these files so that the `%20` is removed and replaced with a space instead?

Comment: My mistake, I tried searching but it must have evaded my efforts. The answers here are pretty useful and well explained though.

Comment: And the question is quite useful in itself when generalised to undo URI encoding.

Comment: Also covered in the following question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159253/decoding-url-encoding-percent-encoding?lq=1 (which to me seems pretty duplicate to this one in some way)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Debian and derivatives (including Ubuntu), you could use `rename`, which applies a Perl expression to each file name.

```
rename 's/%20/ /g' L*
        |  |  | |   |
        |  |  | |   +--- Files to match
        |  |  | +------- globally
        |  |  +--------- with space
        |  +------------ %20
        +--------------- Substitute
```

I would consider using underscore instead of space – as it generally makes life easier in the cli world.

To generalise to all URI encoding:

```
rename 'use URI::Escape; $_ = uri_unescape $_' *%*
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `deurlname` from [renameutils](http://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/).

```
$ ls
L4%20Molecular%20Recognition.pdf
$ deurlname L4%20Molecular%20Recognition.pdf
$ ls
L4 Molecular Recognition.pdf
```

---

I wrote [a script](https://github.com/EvanTeitelman/utils/blob/master/viname) that allows you to rename files in an editor.

You just pass the script a filename and it opens your editor with the filename
in it. Then you edit the filename, write, and close the editor.

```
$ ls
  L4%20Molecular%20Recognition.pdf
$ viname L4%20Molecular%20Recognition.pdf
  ======================
  L4%20Molecular%20Recognition.pdf█
  ======================

  ======================
  L4-Molecular-Recognition.pdf█
  ======================
  (pretend this is an editor)
$ ls
  L4-Molecular-Recognition.pdf
```

---

I also wrote [a script](https://github.com/EvanTeitelman/utils/blob/master/nf)
that automatically renames files to conform to my preferred naming scheme. When
I download files, the first thing I do is call this script on them.

```
$ ls
  L4%20Molecular%20Recognition.pdf
$ nf L4%20Molecular%20Recognition.pdf
  'L4%20Molecular%20Recognition.pdf' renamed to 'l4-molecular-recognition.pdf'
$ ls
  L4-molecular-recognition.pdf
```

Be careful with that script. It can do some rather dramatic renames. Use its
dry run (`nf -n`) option before renaming any files.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `convmv` in the directory where you have the files:
To test what the output would be:

```
convmv --unescape *%20*
```

To actually rename the files add `--notest`:

```
convmv --unescape --notest *%20*
```

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative that doesn't rely on external tools outside of bash:

```bash
for old in *; do
    new="${old//+/ }"
    printf -v new '%b' "${new//%/\x}"
    mv -- "$old" "$new"
done
```

Comment: Great answer if you've come upon this page looking for a MacOS solution (like me).

Answer (score 0):

For some Linux users, the `rename` command in the [the best answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76502/208716) won't work.

As described [here](https://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Rename), another non-Perl `rename` program is also available, which is provided as part of the `util-linux` project.

The syntax for the same command (for files starting with `L`) with the util-linux command is:

```
rename '%20' ' ' L*
```