# Decoding URL encoding (percent encoding)

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, url

I want to decode URL encoding, is there any built-in tool for doing this or could anyone provide me with a `sed` code that will do this?

I did search a bit through [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com) and on the internet but I couldn't find any command line tool for decoding url encoding.

What I want to do is simply in place edit a `txt` file so that:

- `%21` becomes `!`
- `%23` becomes `#`
- `%24` becomes `$`
- `%26` becomes `&`
- `%27` becomes `'`
- `%28` becomes `(`
- `%29` becomes `)`

And so on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250698/how-to-decode-url-encoded-string-in-shell

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Found these Python one liners that do what you want:

#### Python2

```
$ alias urldecode='python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; \
    print ul.unquote_plus(sys.argv[1])"'

$ alias urlencode='python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; \
    print ul.quote_plus(sys.argv[1])"'
```

#### Python3

```
$ alias urldecode='python3 -c "import sys, urllib.parse as ul; \
    print(ul.unquote_plus(sys.argv[1]))"'

$ alias urlencode='python3 -c "import sys, urllib.parse as ul; \
    print (ul.quote_plus(sys.argv[1]))"'
```

#### Example

```
$ urldecode 'q+werty%3D%2F%3B'
q werty=/;

$ urlencode 'q werty=/;'
q+werty%3D%2F%3B
```

#### References

- [Urlencode and urldecode from a command line](https://web.archive.org/web/20110111070924/http://www.ruslanspivak.com:80/2010/06/02/urlencode-and-urldecode-from-a-command-line/)

Comment: I know this very late, but is there any way i can do this with in place editing?

Comment: @DisplayName - sounds like a new Q to me. I'd ask it, and reference this one.

Comment: streaming: `cat your_lovely_file.csv| python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; [sys.stdout.write(ul.quote_plus(l)) for l in sys.stdin]"`

Comment: See @DIG mbl's answer beblow for one that works with stdin.

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)```

I added `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` to fix it.

Answer (score 89):

#### sed

Try the following command line:

```
$ sed 's@+@ @g;s@%@\\x@g' file | xargs -0 printf "%b"
```

or the following alternative using `echo -e`:

```
$ sed -e's/%\([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\)/\\\\\x\1/g' file | xargs echo -e
```

<sup>Note: The above syntax may not convert `+` to spaces, and can eat all the newlines.</sup>

---

You may define it as alias and add it to your shell *rc* files:

```
$ alias urldecode='sed "s@+@ @g;s@%@\\\\x@g" | xargs -0 printf "%b"'
```

Then every time when you need it, simply go with:

```
$ echo "http%3A%2F%2Fwww" | urldecode
http://www
```

---

#### Bash

When scripting, you can use the following syntax:

```
input="http%3A%2F%2Fwww"
decoded=$(printf '%b' "${input//%/\\x}")
```

However above syntax won't handle pluses (`+`) correctly, so you've to replace them with spaces via `sed` or as suggested by [@isaac](/users/265604/isaac), use the following syntax:

```
decoded=$(input=${input//+/ }; printf "${input//%/\\x}")
```

You can also use the following `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` functions:

```
urlencode() {
    # urlencode <string>
    local length="${#1}"
    for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do
        local c="${1:i:1}"
        case $c in
            [a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]) printf "$c" ;;
            *) printf '%%%02X' "'$c" ;;
        esac
    done
}
 
urldecode() {
    # urldecode <string>
 
    local url_encoded="${1//+/ }"
    printf '%b' "${url_encoded//%/\\x}"
}
```

> Note that above `urldecode()` assumes the data contains no backslash.

Here is similar Joel's version found at: https://github.com/sixarm/urldecode.sh

---

#### bash + xxd

Bash function with `xxd` tool:

```
urlencode() {
  local length="${#1}"
  for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do
    local c="${1:i:1}"
    case $c in
      [a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]) printf "$c" ;;
    *) printf "$c" | xxd -p -c1 | while read x;do printf "%%%s" "$x";done
  esac
done
}
```

Found in [cdown's gist file](https://gist.github.com/cdown/1163649), also at [stackoverflow](//stackoverflow.com/q/6250698).

---

#### PHP

Using PHP you can try the following command:

```
$ echo oil+and+gas | php -r 'echo urldecode(fgets(STDIN));' // Or: php://stdin
oil and gas
```

or just:

```
php -r 'echo urldecode("oil+and+gas");'
```

Use `-R` for multiple line input.

---

#### Perl

In Perl you can use [`URI::Escape`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3A%3AEscape).

```
decoded_url=$(perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_unescape($ARGV[0])' "$encoded_url")
```

Or to process a file:

```
perl -i -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_unescape($ARGV[0])' file
```

---

#### awk

Try [anon](//stackoverflow.com/a/14000368/55075) solution:

```
awk -niord '{printf RT?$0chr("0x"substr(RT,2)):$0}' RS=%..
```

<sup>Note: Parameter `-n` is specific to GNU `awk`.</sup>

Try [Stéphane Chazelas](/a/685091) urlencode solution:

```
awk -v RS='&#[0-9]+;' -v ORS= '1;RT{printf("%%%02X", substr(RT,3))}'
```

See: [Using awk printf to urldecode text](//stackoverflow.com/q/3728049).

#### decoding file names

If you need to remove url encoding from the file names, use `deurlname` tool from `renameutils` (e.g. `deurlname *.*`).

See also:

- [Can wget decode uri file names when downloading in batch?](//superuser.com/q/783337)
- [How to remove URI encoding from file names?](/q/76500)

---

Related:

- [How to decode URL-encoded string in shell?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6250698) at SO
- [How can I encode and decode percent-encoded strings on the command line?](//askubuntu.com/q/53770) at Ask Ubuntu

Comment: `awk`: As this makes use of a library function, `chr()`, there is a high probability it will solely work on GNU awk (`gawk`).  However, in this case there will be hardly any equivalent for POSIX `awk`, because the `-n` option (allowing non-decimal arguments) *IS* a GNU `awk` specialty.

Comment: Your first `sed` code gives me `xargs: argument line too long` for a file with ≥2164 lines.

Comment: @Sparhawk Try the second sed example, or try adding `-L1` to xargs to split the lines being read. For more complex input, you should avoid xargs or piping in the shell, but try parsing the file directly, like using php.

Comment: @kenorb adding `-L1` to the first `sed` code didn't help; I get the same error. The second `sed` code doesn't work perfectly, either. It doesn't convert `+` to spaces, and eats all the newlines.

Comment: Your solutions involving `printf` do not take into account that the url might contain escaped percentage signs like `%25`. You pass these to printf without escaping them for printf with another percentage sign like `%%`.

Comment: ```perl -i -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_unescape($ARGV[0])' ``` works only when I pass the content of the file ( the string to decode ) and not with the file name: i.e ```perl -i -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_unescape($ARGV[0])' Q28367``` where Q28367 is a filename that contains url encoded prints out ```Q28367``` (perl 5, version 18)

Comment: The bash version requires `local LC_ALL=C` at the top, otherwise all wide characters (i.e Japanese, Chinese, etc.) are not properly broken into bytes.

Comment: https://github.com/SixArm/urlencode.sh

Comment: The printf versions don't work when using BSD version of printf (eg macOS), however it works fine when using the GNU Coreutils version.

Comment: Make the bash line `decoded=$(input=${input//+/ }; printf "${input//%/\\x}")` and it would manage the conversion of `+` just fine.

Answer (score 22):

There is a built-in function for that in the Python standard library. In Python 2, it's [`urllib.unquote`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote).

```
decoded_url=$(python2 -c 'import sys, urllib; print urllib.unquote(sys.argv[1])' "$encoded_url")
```

Or to process a file:

```
python2 -c 'import sys, urllib; print urllib.unquote(sys.stdin.read())' <file >file.new &&
mv -f file.new file
```

In Python 3, it's [`urllib.parse.unquote`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote).

```
decoded_url=$(python3 -c 'import sys, urllib.parse; print(urllib.parse.unquote(sys.argv[1]))' "$encoded_url")
```

Or to process a file:

```
python3 -c 'import sys, urllib.parse; print(urllib.parse.unquote(sys.stdin.read()))' <file >file.new &&
mv -f file.new file
```

In Perl you can use [`URI::Escape`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3A%3AEscape).

```
decoded_url=$(perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_unescape($ARGV[0])' "$encoded_url")
```

Or to process a file:

```
perl -pli -MURI::Escape -e '$_ = uri_unescape($_)' file
```

If you want to stick to POSIX portable tools, it's awkward, because the only serious candidate is awk, which doesn't parse hexadecimal numbers. See [Using awk printf to urldecode text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728049/using-awk-printf-to-urldecode-text) for examples with common awk implementations, including BusyBox.

Answer (score 19):

Perl one liner:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\%(\w\w)/chr hex $1/ge'
```

Example:

```
$ echo '%21%22' |  perl -pe 's/\%(\w\w)/chr hex $1/ge'
!"
```

or if you want to ignore non-hex sequences like `%zz` (which the above mangles)

```
$ perl -pe 's/\%([[:xdigit:]]{2})/chr hex $1/ge'
```

Comment: This answer is attractive when you don't want to deal with installing perl modules.

Comment: Only one that worked elegantly for me on MacOS.

Comment: If you want to resolve all of the levels of URL encoding at once, there's also `perl -pe 's/\%([[:xdigit:]]{2})/chr hex $1/ge while (/\%[[:xdigit:]]{2}/);'` which will decode all the `%25xx` nested encodings

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use a simple-minded `sed` command, then use the following:

```
sed -e 's/%21/!/g' -e 's/%23/#/g' -e 's/%24/$/g' -e 's/%26/\&/g' -e "s/%27/'/g" -e 's/%28/(/g' -e 's/%29/)/g'
```

But it is more convenient to create a script like (say `sedscript`):

```
s/%21/!/g
s/%23/#/g
s/%24/$/g
s/%26/\&/g
s/%27/'/g
s/%28/(/g
s/%29/)/g
```

Then run `sed -f sedscript < old > new`, which will output as you desired.

---

For an ease, the command [`urlencode`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/urlencode) is also available directly in `gridsite-clients` package can be installed from (by `sudo apt-get install gridsite-clients` in Ubuntu/Debian system).

> NAME
>
>   urlencode - convert strings to or from URL-encoded form
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
>   `urlencode [-m|-d] string [string ...]`
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
>   `urlencode`
>   encodes strings according to RFC 1738.
>
> That is, characters `A`-`Z` `a`-`z` `0`-`9` `.` `_` and `-` are
>   passed through unmodified, but all other characters are represented as %HH,
>   where HH is their two-digit upper-case hexadecimal ASCII representation.
>   For example, the URL `http://www.gridpp.ac.uk/` becomes `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gridpp.ac.uk%2F`
>
> `urlencode` converts each character in all the strings
>   given on the command line.  If multiple strings are given,
>   they are concatenated with separating spaces before conversion.
>   OPTIONS
>
>   `-m`
>     Instead of full conversion, do GridSite "mild URL encoding"
>       in which A-Z a-z 0-9 . = - _ @ and / are passed through unmodified. 
>       This results in slightly more human-readable strings
>       but the application must be prepared to create or simulate
>       the directories implied by any slashes.
>   `-d`
>     Do URL-decoding rather than encoding, according to RFC 1738. 
>       %HH and %hh strings are converted and other characters are passed through
>       unmodified, with the exception that
>     `+`
>     is converted to space.

Example of decoding URL:

```
$ urlencode -d "http%3a%2f%2funix.stackexchange.com%2f"
http://unix.stackexchange.com/

$ urlencode -d "Example: %21, %22, . . . , %29 etc"
Example: !, ", . . . , ) etc
```

Comment: For tutorial on `sed` [visit](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: This is a bad solution, because it requires hardcoding every character. This problem is exemplified by your code missing the often used `%20` escape sequence.

Comment: @Overv I've just Revised

Comment: Also, you might want to double-check what `s/%26/&/g` does.  (I fixed it.)

Comment: Not up on my RFCs, but `RFC-1738` appears superceded by `RFC-3986`: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

Answer (score 7):

GNU Awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -fn
@include "ord"
BEGIN {
   RS = "%.."
}
{
   printf "%s", $0
   if (RT != "") {
      printf "%s", chr("0x" substr(RT, 2)) 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I can't comment on [best answer in this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159254/123606), so here is mine.

Personally, I use these aliases for URL encoding and decoding:

```
alias urlencode='python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.quote(  sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else sys.stdin.read()[0:-1])"'

alias urldecode='python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.unquote(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else sys.stdin.read()[0:-1])"'
```

Both commands allow you to convert data, passed as a **command line argument** or read it from **standard input**, because both one-liners check whether there are command line arguments (even empty ones) and process them or just read standard input otherwise.

---

### update 2017-05-23 (slash encoding)

In response to the @Bevor's comment.

If you also need to encode the slash, just add an empty second argument to the quote function, then the slash will also be encoded.

So, finally `urlencode` *alias* in *bash* looks like this:

```
alias urlencode='python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.quote(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else sys.stdin.read()[0:-1], \"\")"'
```

### Example

```
$ urlencode "Проба пера/Pen test"
%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%2FPen%20test

$ echo "Проба пера/Pen test" | urlencode
%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%2FPen%20test

$ urldecode %D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%2FPen%20test
Проба пера/Pen test

$ echo "%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%2FPen%20test" | urldecode
Проба пера/Pen test

$ urlencode "Проба пера/Pen test" | urldecode
Проба пера/Pen test

$ echo "Проба пера/Pen test" | urlencode | urldecode
Проба пера/Pen test
```

Comment: Does not encode slashes.

Comment: @Bevor: Example?

Comment: Add a slash to urlencode "Проба пера" -> result: Slash is not encoded.

Comment: @Bevor: You are right. Thank you for your comment. I will also change my answer to reflect your comment in it.

Comment: Very slight improvement. Join argv with spaces. Ex:
`alias urlencode='python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.quote(  \" \".join(sys.argv[1:]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else sys.stdin.read()[0:-1])"'`.

Answer (score 5):

And another Perl approach:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use URI::Encode;
my $uri     = URI::Encode->new( { encode_reserved => 0 } );
while (<>) {

    print $uri->decode($_)
}
```

You will need to install the `URI::Encode` module. On my Debian, I could simply run

```
sudo apt-get install liburi-encode-perl
```

Then, I ran the script above on a test file containing:

```
http://foo%21asd%23asd%24%26asd%27asd%28asd%29
```

The result was (I had saved the script as `foo.pl`):

```
$ ./foo.pl
http://foo!asd#asd$&asd'asd(asd)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution using ruby (accepted python answer wasn't working for me)

```bsh
alias urldecode='ruby -e "require \"cgi\"; puts CGI.unescape(ARGV[0])"'
alias urlencode='ruby -e "require \"cgi\"; puts CGI.escape(ARGV[0])"'
```

## Example

```bsh
$ urldecode 'q+werty%3D%2F%3B'
q werty=/;

$ urlencode 'q werty=/;'
q+werty%3D%2F%3B
```

Comment: Just used to ruby, and these statements look smaller.  Also, I changed to ARGF.read so I can pipe it in like I do with many other utilities!

Comment: The command can be simplified by passing the flag `-r cgi` instead of embedding `require \"cgi\";` in the code. Also, I like @Pysis’s idea above but suggest `$stdin.read.chomp` because [`ARGF`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/ARGF.html)’s extra features don’t make sense for this use case and because we don’t want to process the ending newline. After these changes: `ruby -r cgi -e "puts CGI.unescape($stdin.read.chomp)"`

Answer (score 3):

An answer in (mostly Posix) shell:

```
$ input='%21%22'
$ printf "`printf "%s\n" "$input" | sed -e 's/+/ /g' -e 's/%\(..\)/\\\\x\1/g'`"
!"
```

Explanation:

- `-e 's/+/ /g` transforms each `+` in space (as described in url-encode norm)
- `-e 's/%\(..\)/\\\\x\1/g'` transform each `%XX` in `\\xXX`. Notice one of `\` will be removed by quoting rules.
- The inner printf is just there to pass input to sed. We may replace it by any other mechanism
- The outer printf interpret `\\xXX` sequences and display result.

**Edit:**

Since `%` should always been interpreted in URLs, it is possible to simplify this answer. In add, I think it is cleaner to use `xargs` instead of *backquotes* (thanks to @josch).

```
$ input='%21%22+%25'
$ printf "%s\n" "$input" | sed -e 's/+/ /g; s/%/\\x/g' | xargs -0 printf
!" %
```

Unfortunately, (as @josch noticed) none of these solutions are Posix compliant since `\x` escape sequence is not defined in Posix.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Perhaps you could explain this answer and how it works. We generally prefer our answers to be long form with details, not just code snippets.

Comment: I really like this answer because it's comprehensive, portable and doesn't require extra heavier external programs like perl or python. Works well for me.

Comment: Great solution. And even shorter and smarter: `... | sed 's/+/ /g;s/%\(..\)/\\\\x\1/g'`. The `-e` option can be omitted here in fact...

Comment: In which Posix shell can you confirm your solution to work? If I execute your statements, then I get this printed: `\x21\x22`. A fix that works for me is to replace the `printf "printf ... | sed ..."` construct by `printf ... | sed ... | xargs printf`. I assume the problem is with how characters get expanded in my shell when passing them through a doubly quoted string to the outer printf. I'm using dash on Debian as my Posix shell.

Comment: Your solution does not take into account that the url might contain escaped percentage signs like `%25`. You pass these to printf without escaping them for printf with another percentage sign like `%%`. This will let printf show an error "missing hexadecimal number in escape" and the percentage sign will be discarded.

Comment: @josch You are right, `printf` is a built-in in `dash` and it doesn't recognize `\x` escaping. You can use `/usr/bin/printf` instead of `printf` in order to make it work. Normally, you should be able to use `command printf`, but it seems to not work as it should. It continue to use built-in.

Comment: I suggest this: `printf "%s" "$input" | sed 's/+/ /g; s/%\(..\)/\\x\1/g' | xargs -0 printf`

Comment: @Jezz indeed support for `\x` escaping is not part of POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html

During my tests I saw another problem. You might want to replace your `..` regex by `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]` because otherwise input like '%%%' will fail.

I also added `s/%/%%/g` at the end to make sure to escape percentages for printf.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a BASH function to do exactly that:

```
function urldecode() {
        echo -ne $(echo -n "$1" | sed -E "s/%/\\\\x/g")
}
```

Comment: works like charm

Comment: If you want to convert `+` characters to spaces and not spawn any processes, you can use this: `: "${1//+/ }" && echo -e "${_//%/\\x}"`

Comment: I tried loads and this was the only one that worked, I had to move it out of the function and changed $1 to my variable though.

Answer (score 2):

Shell-only:

```
$ x='a%20%25%e3%81%82';printf "${x//\%/\\x}"
a %あ
```

Add `--` or `%b` to prevent arguments that start with a dash from being treated as options.

In zsh `${x//%/a}` adds `a` to the end but `${x//\%/a}` replaces `%` with `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the relevant bits from another script *(that I just shamelessly stole from my [youtube.com download script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161754/52934) from another answer)* I've written before. It uses `sed` and the shell to build up a working urldecode.

```
set \! \" \# \$ \% \& \' \( \) \* \ \+ \, \/ \: \; \= \? \@ \[ \]
for c do set "$@" "'$c" "$c"; shift; done
curl -s "$url" | sed 's/\\u0026/\&/g;'"$(
    printf 's/%%%X/\\%s/g;' "$@"
)"
```

I wont swear it's comprehensive - and in fact I doubt it - but it handled youtube surely enough.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Using Raku's `URI::Encode` module, which purports to be  [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)  compliant (just like Perl5's `URI::Encode` and/or `URI::Escape` modules):*

```
~$ raku -MURI::Encode -ne 'put uri_decode($_);'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
http://www.example.com/?name=john%20doe&age=54
```

Sample Output:

```
http://www.example.com/?name=john doe&age=54
```

---

Note, if you're looking for a more full-blown URL parser, try Raku's `URL` module. Sample Output (below) with same input as above:

```
~$ raku -MURL -ne 'my $url = URL.new($_); .raku.put for $url;'  file
URL.new(scheme => "http", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "www.example.com", port => Int, path => [], query => {:age("54"), :name("john\%20doe")}, fragment => Str)
```

With the second approach, you can extract only the elements you really need decoded, like the URL `query` subcomponent, and decode as key/value pairs:

```
~$ raku -MURL -MURI::Encode -ne 'my $url = URL.new($_); for $url.query.kv -> $k,$v {say $k => uri_decode($v)};'  file
age => 54
name => john doe
```

https://github.com/raku-community-modules/URI-Encode
https://raku.land/cpan:TYIL/URL
https://raku.org

Comment: Using `$*IN` instead of `$_` allows for reading from standard input, like so: `echo 'name=john%20doe&age=54' | raku -M URI::Escape -e 'put uri_unescape($*IN.get)'`

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for **short** strings (shell is slowwww):

```
$ str='q+werty%3D%2F%3B'

$ a=${str//+/ };printf "$(echo "${a//%/\\x}")\n"

q werty=/;
```

Answer (score 0):

From my laymen research of the topic, it appears that the implementations of the percent-encoding are susceptible to ambiguity in edge cases, such as character encoding potentially being different than expected, characters not escaped, query part being encoded differently, potential presence of binary and non-ASCII characters, etc. So, some analysis of and assumptions about the input data are necessary.

The closest to a dedicated tool are respective functions in programming languages, such as Python's functions from `urllib` module, which makes some sane assumptions about the URL data, as evidenced by the comments in [cpython's code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/urllib/parse.py). That's why I find the current top answer being good.

As a matter of exercise, I implemented a similar alias with GNU Guile, since it is in path by default on a GNU Guix system with Python not necessarily being present in path. I cannot comment on reliability in comparison to Python, Perl, or other solutions. The [documentation suggests](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/URIs.html#index-uri_002ddecode) that one should preferably split the URL on `?`, `&`, and `=`, and process the query separately from the path, as well as split the path into segments with a dedicated function, and still be ready for errors. However, I am satisfied with the results on full URL strings copied from a browser.

```bash
alias urldecode='guile -c "(use-modules (web uri))
                           (display (uri-decode (cadr (command-line))))
                           (newline)"'
```

`(web uri)` module provides `uri-decode` function for decoding URIs. `command-line` passes the arguments. `cadr` picks the second item in the list (which is the URL being the first argument after the executable name itself, i.e. `guile`).

```bash
$ urldecode "http://ephsheir.uhsp.edu.ua/bitstream/handle/8989898989/2850/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%20%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%20%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b8.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y"
http://ephsheir.uhsp.edu.ua/bitstream/handle/8989898989/2850/Макет Народни назви.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y
```

A one-liner when not having an alias:

```bash
$ guile -c "(use-modules (web uri)) (display (uri-decode (cadr (command-line)))) (newline)" "http://ephsheir.uhsp.edu.ua/bitstream/handle/8989898989/2850/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%20%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%20%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b8.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y"
http://ephsheir.uhsp.edu.ua/bitstream/handle/8989898989/2850/Макет Народни назви.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y
```

Comment: The encoding algorithm itself is unambiguous, of course, but as you note, there is no way to indicate which encoding to use for the resulting text. The RFCs have evolved over the years so that the current default assumption should usually be UTF-8, but legacy systems previously used ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 in accordance with previous specs as well as various ad-hoc conventions.

Answer (score 0):

## AIX/Solaris

This recently came up again and I wanted a non-pythonic version that'd work on AIX/Solaris etc.

```
INPUTSTRING="test%20%21%22%23%24%25%3f%2f%2e%5ctest"
for C in `echo "${INPUTSTRING}" | sed 's/%\(..\)/ %\1 /g'`
do
  case "$C" in
    %*)
      echo $C | sed 's/%//' | (echo 16i; tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'; echo P) | dc
      ;; 
    *)
      printf "%s" "$C"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

In essence, tokenizes the string and then for each token,
if it's not a `%` sequence, just print it. 
Otherwise trim the `%` and run it through `dc` with 16i radix.

Relies on dc, sed and POSIX features of printf (no `\x` encoding).

Here it is as a "1-liner":

```
for C in `echo "test%20%21%22%23%24%25%3f%2f%2e%5ctest" | sed 's/%\(..\)/ %\1 /g'`; do case "$C" in %*) echo $C | sed 's/%//' | (echo 16i; tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'; echo P) | dc ;; *) printf "%s" "$C" ;; esac; done
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't use `sed` but `zsh` (specifically about `.ohmyzsh` plugin) you can use the function `omz_urldecode` to parse any `%##` to a readable string:

```bash
omz_urldecode 'http://example.com/some%23'
#Output:
http://example.com/some#
```

You can test your examples `%##` with a for:

```bash
for ((i=21; i<=29; i++)); do 
  omz_urldecode "http://example.com/exa_%${i}mple"
done
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/exa_!mple
http://example.com/exa_"mple
http://example.com/exa_#mple
http://example.com/exa_$mple
http://example.com/exa_%mple
http://example.com/exa_&mple
http://example.com/exa_'mple
http://example.com/exa_(mple
http://example.com/exa_)mple
```

---

If you have `ohmyzsh` installed in your system you can use this command in zsh to figure out where is defined that function:

```
type -a omz_urldecode
omz_urldecode is a shell function from /home/user/.oh-my-zsh/lib/functions.zsh
```

And to see what that function has:

```bash
type -f omz_urldecode
#Output
omz_urldecode () {
        emulate -L zsh
        local encoded_url=$1 
        local caller_encoding=$langinfo[CODESET] 
        local LC_ALL=C 
        export LC_ALL
        local tmp=${encoded_url:gs/+/ /} 
        tmp=${tmp:gs/\\/\\\\/} 
        tmp=${tmp:gs/%/\\x/} 
        local decoded="$(printf -- "$tmp")" 
        local -a safe_encodings
        safe_encodings=(UTF-8 utf8 US-ASCII) 
        if [[ -z ${safe_encodings[(r)$caller_encoding]} ]]
        then
                decoded=$(echo -E "$decoded" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t $caller_encoding) 
                if [[ $? != 0 ]]
                then
                        echo "Error converting string from UTF-8 to $caller_encoding" >&2
                        return 1
                fi
        fi
        echo -E "$decoded"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Must have changed my approach from [my earlier comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159253/decoding-url-encoding-percent-encoding/510379?noredirect=1#comment1055130_510379), probably for a quick tool install instead of coding and/or any manual setup.

Now I use this:

```
npm i -g url-cli
xout | url -dp | xio; # Linux + Aliases
gc; gc | tr -d '\n' | url -dp | pc; gc; # Windows-Cygwin + Aliases
```