# Can you do url (percent) encoding with the recode terminal tool

Tags: utilities

You can use the `recode` tool to do html encoding and decoding like so:

```
recode html..ascii
```

Can you also do URL-Encoding (percent encoding) with it?

Comment: recode is not Bash-specific. It is an independent command-line tool that can be run from any shell.

Comment: Looks like `recode --list` will show you all the formats accepted: from the  [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/recode). Not much obvious information from a quick glance at the source https://github.com/pinard/Recode . The [home page](http://recode.progiciels-bpi.ca/) is no longer available.

Comment: This isn't really at the level at which `recode` operates, is it? If I'm not mistaken it primarily deals with character set encodings (like ASCII UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1), not Content-Encoding like base64, %-encoding, or (stretching it a bit) compression.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: no

I wrote a little script to exhaustively test each charset recognized by recode. None succeeded. I am running recode 3.7.6.

```
charsets=$(recode -l)
for charset in $charsets; do
  result=$(echo ' ' | recode ascii..${charset} 2>/dev/null)
  if [ "${result}" == '%20' ]; then echo $charset; fi
done
```

**Note:** this may help:  [Decoding URL encoding (percent encoding)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159253)

Comment: Hmm. The question asks about *encoding,* but your answer addresses *decoding.*